# Finding out which button i'm pressing in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter-button

I'm making a project which requires me to make 270 buttons in tkinter, I'm creating them via a loop and i need to add functionality to them. In order for them to be functional for my purpose I need to find out which button is being pressed how do i do this?

heres my code (dont worry about the loads of comments, its necessary as its for a project for my exams)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldw3F.png)

The blue part is where the buttons are created. Thanks

I've really not tried anything, I've tried to get the text of the button's as this will be actually what I want. The buttons are named after all the London Underground stations and so getting the text of the button will be sufficient. I just dont rlly know what I'm doing

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code directly in your post as a formatted code block instead of an image?  It help for searches and for writing answers

Answer (score 1):

It seems the CTkButton object has an parameter called `command` to which you can pass a callback function (see [here](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkButton#example-code)).

In this case, using a lambda function should be the best approach.

```py
for line in stations_reader:
    ct.CTkButton(frame, text=line[0], font=(Ariel, 15), command=lambda: line[0]).grid(row=(int(line[5])+1),column=0)
    ct.CTkButton(frame, text=line[0], font=(Ariel, 15), command=lambda: line[0]).grid(row=(int(line[5])+1),column=0)
```

I think this should roughly get you the behaviour you want, based on your question, but make sure to comment if you have any questions.